# Tableview disable user interaction in cells

Tags: swift, tableview

I have a cell in a UITableView with a UITextField in it and when i tap the cell the Keyboard pops up. But what I want is that the didSelectRow function gets called instead.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

What works is if I set the textField isUserInteractionEnabled to false but then becomeFirstResponder doesn't work anymore.

So is there any property to set so that only the didSelectRowAt functions gets called. A bit like if the allowsSelectionDuringEditing?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two (not clear) possible ways:

- You can add a transparent UIView over the textField so you can't tap on it.
- Another solution is to set the textField `isUserInteractionEnabled = true` after the cell selection and then set it to false in the `textFieldShouldEndEditing` delegate.